# Problems with exporting model to Godot

Tags: rigging, armature, export

I'm trying to import a model I made on Blender onto a project on Godot, but the gun is always way off position wise.

This is how it's supposed to be:
[image: Model in blender]

This is how it's turning out:
[image: Model in Godot]

I have other gun models in the file connected to the same armature, but those turn out absolutely fine.

What do I do?

Comment: I don't know abour Godot but it must be linked to the export in blender. I would suggest you to compare if your guns have transform or not when exporting. Depending of the format you use for export you should have the possibility to export the transform or not. You can also apply the transform by hand before export.

Comment: How do I check if my guns have transform?

Comment: You have a transform tab in the panel on the right side of the 3D view (maybe press N to show the pannel if it is hidden) or go to the object tab propreties. The transform is the location/rotation/scale of the object.

Comment: Doesn't every object have a transform?

Comment: Sure, by no transform I mean that the transform is the default one, 0 for rotation and location and 1 for scale.